# .NET 8 gRPC client authentication problem on macOS

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I have a .NET 8 client code to call a gRPC service and it works **perfectly** on Windows. But when I compile and run the exact same project on macOS I get an `RpcException` with the error message:

> Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 403")

Is there any macOS-specific client configuration that needs to be done for macOS?
Here is the code that I prepare the client with:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new(new SocketsHttpHandler()) {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://..."),
    DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20,
    DefaultVersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact,
    Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
};
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://...", new GrpcChannelOptions() {
    HttpClient = httpClient,
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((c, metadata) => {
        metadata.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
}))});

var client = new MyServiceClient(channel);
var call = client.Method(new Empty());
await foreach(var draft in downCall.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Are you make sure the token is right and contain the right permission?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same token to make get and post queries.